# Python/Django "page not found" error: "The current path, ... , didn’t match any of these."

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Chapter 18  in Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes. I am using Django 4.0.1 and the book uses is 2.2.0 so I see that other people are having similar issues as me with this section.

In other similar stackoverflow questions on this issue, proposed solutions using url instead of path seem also outdated. The solutions on the website therefore are unfortunately not helping me.

**Problem:**
when I open http://localhost:8000/ and I click on "topics" I get the 404 not found error as follows:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/(%25%20url%20'learning_logs:topics'%20%25%7D
Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
topics/ [name='topics']
The current path, (% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}, didn’t match any of these.
```

However, navigating manually to http://localhost:8000/topics shows me the page as intended. I believe this is an issue due to my urls.py located in my app folder.

Here is my urls.py in learning_logs (app), where I think the issue lies:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    #Page that shows all topics.
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    ]
```

Here is my urls.py in learning_log (main project):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Topic

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
    
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

base.html found in template/learning_logs folder:

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}" >Learning Log</a> -
    <a href="(% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}" >Topics</a>
</p>

{% block content %} {% endblock content %}
```

topics.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<p> Topics </p>

<ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
    <li> {{topic}}</li>
    {% empty %}
    <li> No topics have been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

and finally index.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Learning Log helps you keep track of your learning, for any topic you're 
learning about.</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: The `<a href="(% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}" >Topics</a>` did not start the url template tagb with `{%`...

Answer (score 1):

The comment below my question by Willem Van Onsem answered my question, turns out it was a typo.

The Topics did not start the url template tagb with {%... –
Willem Van Onsem